# How to use Teamviewer in vpn mode to access SQl Server?

Tags: sql-server, vpn, teamviewer

I am trying to connect with a customer by creating a VPN with Teamveiwer (I have version 4).

I installed at both ends the von support, I can correctly setup the connection (I can ping succesfully).

When I open management studio to connect to the DB on the remote server it doesn't work.

Team viewer assigned 7.91.40.46 as ip of customer. The sql server instance I am trying to connect to is SQLEXPRESS08.

I tried to connect to `7.91.40.46\SQLEXPRESS08` and `SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS08` but I cannot see the server.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What specific error is it giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to connect by removing the instance name and using the port name instead, so

```
7.91.40.46\SQLEXPRESS08
```

was not working

but

```
7.91.40.46, 3572
```

did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the remote connections setting.  See this post by Larry from a similar question : [SQL Server Can't Connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/191576/sql-server-cant-connect/191587#191587) - specifically at the end of his post where he shows how to enable remote connections.  I'd post it all here by why re-do the work :).